# Laravel: Authenticate against system that checks credentials remotely

Tags: php, authentication, soap, laravel

I have created my own auth provider. The trouble is that I have to auth against a remote system via a soap/xml call.

This call takes a username and password and returns user info if the login was successful.

This approach is radically different from Laravel, where you first have to look up a user then check the credentials.

I thought I could return a dummy user in the retrieveByXXX methods, and do the soap xml call in thevalidateCredentials method, and populate the passed user with the appropriate data. Laravel silently allows this but references to Auth::user() return the dummy info.

Is there a way around this in Laravel? I can add a web service for this but I'd rather not if possible.

Comment: I went ahead and added a web services call for getting the user and credentials. Then I validated from withing laravel per the auth provider interface. Ended up using GenericUser with some custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Auth::once($credentials)
```

From the doc:

> Logging A User In For A Single Request
>
> You may also use the once method to log a user into the application for a single request. No sessions or cookies will be utilized.